# Why does function with callback not executed inside an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK and I am running this code using Lambda. I noticed that when I used upload function with callback inside an async function, it does not execute the function.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  console.log('START UPLOAD')

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'practice-bucket',
    Key: 'hello.txt',
    Body: "hello",
  }
  
  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err, data);
  });

};
```

I know how to make this work. Either by changing the function to a non-async function or by using await and turning the response of upload() into a promise. But I am still curious why wouldn't it execute the upload() function? I am expecting it just to execute it just a regular function since I am not telling it to await.

Comment: There might have been an error while trying to upload the file.

Comment: Apparently, it was always executing the `.upload()` function either with or without `async` and the premise of your question was just confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Javascript's event loop work with async functions in your case the function is returning before s3.upload is complete.

You can fix this issue by converting s3.upload into a promise and then using await to get the result and block the return of your async handler

```
await result = s3.upload(params).promise();
```

Comment: Ohhh, this makes sense. Without await, it will proceed to the next line of code and without waiting to finish the execution of the called function. Thank you!

Comment: @DunkedOreo - So, it was ALWAYS getting called, so the premise of your question was confused.  Did you somehow think it would block and the function wouldn't return until it was done?  Because even adding `await` won't stop the function from returning as soon as you call it.  `async` functions return immediately when you hit the first `await` in them.  They return a promise in the "pending" state.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, yes. I don't work a lot with JS that is why I am still confused with the behavior of async functions. Thank you.

Comment: @DunkedOreo - What I'm confused about is why is this the accepted answer to the question you asked?  Your callback was getting called no matter whether you made your function `async` or not.  This doesn't have anything to do with what you asked about in your question as best I can tell.  And, your function was returning before the upload was complete either with or without `async`.

Comment: @jfriend00 that makes sense, sir. This answer does not specify that the function is always getting called which does not explicitly answer the question. I accepted it  since it explains that the function returns before the function completes. I will submit a proposed edit to this answer to be more explicit, if that's fine.